# Interactive hierarchical data visualization in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, data-visualization, gantt-chart, file-management

I want to visualize age of files in a large directory structure, with the ability to drill down by expanding/collapsing directories. The below linked image represents an idea of what it could look like. [Image: Gantt-like time distribution with collapsible hierarchy levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbTEQ.png)
Boxplot, violin, etc are viable alternatives. A collapsed directory should show timestamps of all files
below that directory in the hierarchy.

Which python data visualization libraries support this type of hierachical, interactive expand/collapse format?

I know how to produce the data, but want to avoid writing the low-level graphical and interactive code in something like pygame or pyglet. I have read about Bokeh, Matplotlib, Seaborn, Plotly, Pygal, Holoviews, PyQtGraph, Pyqwt, Glumpy, Vispy, and Galry buth they don't seem to have the interactive expand/collapse functionality, or do they? Preferred GUI platform is Windows 10 (or browser/javascript ofc).